# Does Islam allow marriage between first cousins?

Tags: nikah

Someone told me that Islam allows marriage between first cousins (who each have a parent that are siblings).  Is this correct?

Comment: see answers in http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/can-i-marry-my-cousins-daughter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What women can't a man marry?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-women-cant-a-man-marry)

Comment: None of those deal with 1st cousins specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Marriage between first cousins in permissible in Islam.

Marriage is only forbidden in Islam when it is between a man and a woman related to him in the ways mentioned in the following verses:

> [Quran 4:22-24](https://quran.com/4/22-24) And do not marry those [women] **whom your fathers
>   married**, except what has already occurred. Indeed, it was an
>   immorality and hateful [to Allah ] and was evil as a way. Prohibited
>   to you [for marriage] are your **mothers**, your **daughters**, your
>   **sisters**, your **father's sisters**, your **mother's sisters**, your **brother's daughters**, your **sister's daughters**, your
>   **[milk] mothers** who nursed you, your **sisters through nursing**, your **wives' mothers**, and your **step-daughters** under your
>   guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if
>   you have not gone in unto them, there is no sin upon you. And [also
>   prohibited are] the **wives of your sons** who are from your [own]
>   loins, and that you take [in marriage] **two sisters simultaneously**,
>   except for what has already occurred. Indeed, Allah is ever Forgiving
>   and Merciful. And [also prohibited to you are all] **married women**
>   except those your right hands possess. [This is] the decree of Allah
>   upon you. And lawful to you are [all others] beyond these, [provided]
>   that you seek them [in marriage] with [gifts from] your property,
>   desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse. So for whatever
>   you enjoy [of marriage] from them, give them their due compensation as
>   an obligation. And there is no blame upon you for what you mutually
>   agree to beyond the obligation. Indeed, Allah is ever Knowing and
>   Wise.

*Additional explanations [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1308/20218).*

First cousins do not come under this ruling since they are not mentioned.

Further we have an example from the Prophet Muhammad (p.b.u.h) himself, he married [Zaynab bint Jash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaynab_bint_Jahsh) who was the first cousin of the Prophet, being the daughter of [Umama bint Abdul-Muttalib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umama_bint_Abdulmuttalib), the sister of the Prophet's father, [Abdullah bin Abdul Mutallib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_ibn_Abdul-Muttalib).

Comment: no wonder so many birth defects in places like Pakistan...

Comment: @amphibient Cousin marriage is permitted, not enforced. The preferable thing is to marry unrelated women and to expand the ties of kinship, [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/72263)

Comment: did i ever say "enforced" ?